# Uso de StringProperty o DoubleProperty con Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx

¿Es posible crear una clase en Java para acceder con hibernate a una tabla de base de datos con *primary key compuesta* (dos o más campos), cuyos atributos con la anotaciones `@Column` son de tipo `StringProperty` o `DoubleProperty` de JavaFX?

Un ejemplo sencillo de lo que pregunto:

*Clase PersonPK*

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

@Embeddable
public class PersonPK implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private StringProperty firstname; 
    private StringProperty lastname;

    public PersonPK(){
        this.firstname= new SimpleStringProperty();
        this.lastname = new SimpleStringProperty();
    }

    public StringProperty firstnameProperty() {
        return firstname;
    }

    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
    public String getfirstname(){
        return this.firstname.get();
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname.set(firstname);
    }

    public StringProperty lastnameProperty() {
        return lastname;
    }

    @Column(name = "LASTNAME")
    public String getLastname(){
        return this.lastname.get();
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname.set(lastname);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((firstname == null) ? 0 : firstname.get().hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((lastname == null) ? 0 : lastname.get().hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        PersonPK other = (PersonPK) obj;
        if (firstname == null) {
            if (other.firstname != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!firstname.get().equals(other.firstname.get()))
            return false;
        if (lastname == null) {
            if (other.lastname != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!lastname.get().equals(other.lastname.get()))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

*Clase Person*

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    PersonPK personPK;

    StringProperty comentario;

    public Person(){
        this.personPK=new PersonPK();
    }

    public PersonPK getPersonPK(){
        return this.personPK;
    }

    public void setPersonPK(PersonPK personPK){
        this.personPK=personPK;
    }

    @Column(name="COMMENTARY")
    public String getComentario(){
        return this.comentario.get();
    }

    public StringProperty comentarioProperty() {
        return comentario;
    }

    public void setComentario(String comentario) {
        this.comentario.set(comentario);
    }
}
```

El error que obtengo es el siguiente:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type
>   for: javafx.beans.property.StringProperty, at table: PERSON, for
>   columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(comentario)]   at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:455)   at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:422)   at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226)     at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:595)
>     at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265)     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:492)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:878)
>     ... 26 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te dice el error es que no encuentra una forma de convertir un objeto de la clase `StringProperty` a un tipo de SQL al momento de hacer el mapeo entre los objetos de Java y los elementos de base de datos. Para esto, podrías crear un conjunto de conversores tal como se explica en la guía de hibernate 5 [3.7.2. Attribute Converter](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/mappingGuide/en-US/html_single/#d5e678).

El código aquí para un conversor:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    PersonPK personPK;

    @Convert( converter = StringPropertyConverter.class )
    StringProperty comentario;
}

@Converter
public class StringPropertyConverter extends implements AttributeConverter<String, StringProperty> {
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(StringProperty value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return value.getValue();
    }

    public StringPropertyconvertToEntityAttribute(String value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        StringProperty result = new StringProperty();
        result.setValue(value);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Personalmente, no considero que esta sea la mejor solución. Puede que JavaFX al momento de inyectar tu atributo `StringProperty` en tu instancia de clase ejecute más sentencias como "amarrar" la propiedad a un campo de la vista, agregar los eventos por listeners, entre otros. Considero que un mejor diseño sería separar la vista del modelo y buscar otra manera de relacionarlos.